# Loading YAML file to an object in Playframework 1.2.X

Tags: java, yaml, playframework-1.x

Is there a way to load YAML to an object that is not a playframework model? 
to load it from yml file from the conf dir to a java object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [snakeYaml](https://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/).

(with dependency `org.yaml -> snakeyaml 1.13`)

```
Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
Object obj = yaml.load(Play.classloader.getResourceAsStream(which + ".yml"));
```

Answer (score 0):

To enable the snakeyaml module, add a line in the /conf/dependencies.yml file, after require:

require:
    - play -> snakeyaml 1.13
run command: play dependencies